# Read YAML file in NESTJS

Tags: yaml, nestjs

Are there any ways to read yaml file in order to generate API DOCs in NESTJS. Can anybody help me with the config? Thanks

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import * as yaml from 'js-yaml';
import { join } from 'path';

const YAML_CONFIG_FILENAME = 'config.yaml';

export default () => {
  return yaml.load(
    readFileSync(join(__dirname, YAML_CONFIG_FILENAME), 'utf8'),
  ) as Record<string, any>;
};
```

I found this from https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration